# Generating invoice numbers based on Financial Year in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using **Google Sheets** to generate invoice numbers. I need help generating invoice numbers based on the financial year starting 1st April every year and ending in March.

I want it to restart counting it for every new FY. like for example, for FY 2021, the Invoice number would be "ETL/2021-22/001", "ETL/2021-22/002" and for the next FY, the invoice number would be "ETL/2022-23/001", "ETL/2022-23/002" etc.

I know how to get the financial year from the date entered. But I need help in counting the invoice numbers in this FY and **restart counting invoice numbers in the next FY** and so on.

- Column A: Date entered for invoice
- Column B: FY generated using formula

`=IF(A:A<>"",IF(MONTH(A:A)<4, YEAR(A:A)-1 &"-"&Right(YEAR(A:A),2), YEAR(A:A) &"-"&right(YEAR(A:A)+1,2)),"")`

- Column C: This is where I want the result.
- Column D: Name of the person/entity to whom the invoice is issued.

**Problem:**
Now, as seen in the image below, If I first want to take an invoice for "Person D" and then issue an invoice for "Person A", I want the **invoice numbers to be sequential** (as the date of invoice falls in the FY) and also I want the **invoice numbers to be static** and not change later on.

(Please let me know either a script or a formula to solve this)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is this really a `google-apps-script` question? If not, you should remove that tag from the question. (It looks as if you want a formula-based solution, not a script-based solution.)

Comment: Did you try to solve this yourself using a script-based approach? If so, that would be helpful to see in the question.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/68182844/13045193 and this [Sheets Forum thread](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/115376818/generating-invoice-numbers-based-on-financial-year?hl=en&msgid=115376818).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added tab invoice1 and an onEdit script to your latest document, "Invoice Sample". All of the dates have been removed from column A. If you enter them, one at a time, in some chosen sequence, the script should populate column C following your guidelines.

The script uses helper columns H and I. Both are generated by formula but only column I changes as new dates are added. It will always display the next three digit number to be assigned for each of the FY in the list. You could hide both columns.

The script is crude and I'm sure doesn't follow recommended conventions because I am a novice at best. It needs work by someone more knowledgeable.

```
       function onEdit(e) {
    // invoice1 tab
    // when a date is entered into column A, column B populates by formula and
    // this script should create the invoice number in column C with the next number 
    // for the relevant FY. The next number is maintained in column I by formula.
    var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    if (sh.getName() !== "invoice1" || e.range.columnStart !== 1 ) return;    
    CFYrng = sh.getRange("H2:I20");
    CFYvals = CFYrng.getValues();
    var Invrng = sh.getRange("C" + e.range.rowStart);
    if(e.range.getValue() === '') Invrng.clearContent();
    if(Invrng.getValue() === '') {
      var FYrng = sh.getRange("B" + e.range.rowStart);
      FY = FYrng.getValue();
      for (i = 0; i < 19; i++){
        if(CFYvals[i][0] === FY){
          invn = CFYvals[i][1];
        }
      }
      var invoice = "ETL/" + FY + "/" + invn;
      Invrng.setValue(invoice);
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally, there is someone in the Stack crowd who exactly understood my question and came up with a solution. Thanks a ton, mate! This worked for me! Please keep up the good work. You definitely deserve applause. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey, I want to insert 3 more columns before the 'Column A' [Column A will be the 4th column]. Can you please let me know the changes in the script (as well as the formula). Since I'm not good with scripts. Here is the link for the sheets in case you need them. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N2BeGJIOd3dDEHY_7tyow3EO0Qes_smGggcK1WkICXY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Insert the 3 columns and the sheet formulas will automatically adjust. code changes:

Comment: Insert the 3 columns and the sheet formulas will automatically adjust. code changes: columnStart !== 4    everywhere there is a column reference by letter, change the letter by 3 columns . e.g.  H2:I becomes K2:L CFYrng = sh.getRange("K2:L20");

Comment: Sure it worked. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your question I've come up with an Apps Script solution. This is also sequential and static as you noted it needing to be.

### Script

The only variable that might need changing is in the first line, and that's the name of the sheet. I've called mine `invoice`, but you can change that to whatever your sheet is called.

```js
function generateInvoiceNumbers() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('invoice');
  const range = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();
  let rowNum = 2;
  let lastRow, number;

  for (const row of range) {

    if (lastRow != row[0]){
      number = 1;
    }
    
    let string;

    if (number < 10) {
      string = '00' + (number);
    } else if( number > 9 && number < 100) {
      string = '0' + (number);
    } else {
      string = number;
    }
    sheet.getRange(rowNum, 3).setValue(`ETL/${row[0]}/${string}`)
    number++;
    rowNum++;
    lastRow = row[0];
  }
}
```

### Results

As you can see, it counts up with every invoice, but as soon as a new FY starts the counter will reset.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your support! But it seems that the code isn't working properly. Can you please check? Im leaving the link for the spreadsheet below.
Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N2BeGJIOd3dDEHY_7tyow3EO0Qes_smGggcK1WkICXY/edit#gid=0

Comment: Your sheet is private, either make it view per link or public. Also, what exactly isn't working? Have you changed the `sheet` variable so it suits your sheet?

Comment: It's not working because you've left certain A and B rows empty, fill all necessary cells (A and B 4, 5, 6 etc). Either that or I'll have to change the code given a bit

Comment: Yes, I've tried filling the blank cells as you said. But there is no change. I've tried the ways I've known. But I'm unable to understand the cause of the problem. And I'm thankful that you've tried reaching out. But, as you said 'Column B' will be auto-populated based on the date entered in 'Column A'.  And, 'Column A' is not entered sequentially. It will always be entered in random rows (as per the requirement).

Comment: Also, I'm leaving a new spreadsheet link here with the same data <https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z29fzNMgxcw-eO6fnkP1iR0WtosY0KhSnbMJ_YGSQfA/edit?usp=sharing>. You can please go through and make any necessary changes if required. (Please ignore the previous spreadsheet link if you have)